# \multirow adapting the height of the merged rows

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow

I'm trying to crate a Table with pretty much text in their cells. Some cells are merged (\multirow). By the merged cells, the line height doesn't adapt automatically and the text spills over the cell above.
Is there a solution to automatically adapt the height depending on the amount of text under multirow?
Many thanks in advance.
Lenny
[image: the error]

````
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{array} % for tables
\usepackage{tabularx}% for tables  
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth} {
  |p{\dimexpr.15\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}% column 1
  |p{\dimexpr.2\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}% column 2
  |p{\dimexpr.325\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}% column 3
  |p{\dimexpr.325\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}|% column 4
  }
\hline
 Cell1 & Cell2 & Cell3 & Cell4 \\
\hline
Lorem ipsum dolor sit  & 
amet, consectetur adipiscing &
\multirow{2}{=}{elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur} 

& \multirow{2}{=}{Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum ed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium} \\ \cline{1-2}  

aspernatur aut odit aut fugit  & sed quia consequuntur magni &   &  \\ 
\hline

 numquam eius modi  & tempora incidunt ut labore & Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in & ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}]```
````

Comment: You could probably avoid the issue by rotating the table to a landscape oriented page.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but why do you use `tabularx` without a single `X` type column? If you prefer manually  calculating the required column widths, just as you did in the MWE, a regular `tabular` would be sufficient.

Comment: Hmm maybe try placing the multirow cells one row below, and use -2 for the number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

With long text in cells, it is better to separate the cell content from the table layout to better visualize the latter.
In this case 10 cells are used.

The cell with the longest text will dominate the table layout, so
we start by adding row 1 col 3 in a multi-row cell, top alignment.

With the width assigned to column 3, it creates 15 lines, so it will require 14 empty cells below.

Consequently, we use `\multirow[t]{15}{=}{\ciii}` to fill this cell. Similarly with the cell in column 4, row 1.

Now we have to decide how to divide the 15 rows in column 1 to add the two 3-line cells. We choose 7 rows for the top cell and 8 rows for the bottom cell.
An equal arrangement is used in column 2.

To finish the third row of the table, we repeat the same procedure, starting with the second cell of column 2, with 9 lines of text.

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{array} % for tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}}

\begin{document}        
    
%% Define the cell contents 
\newcommand{\ci}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit}
\newcommand{\cii}{amet, consectetur adipiscing}
\newcommand{\ciii}{elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur}
\newcommand{\civ}{Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum ed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium}
\newcommand{\cv}{aspernatur aut odit aut fugit}
\newcommand{\cvi}{sed quia consequuntur magni}
\newcommand{\cvii}{numquam eius modi}
\newcommand{\cviii}{tempora incidunt ut labore}
\newcommand{\cix}{Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in}    
\newcommand{\cx}{a voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?}    

% Table layout

\begin{tabular}{| P{.15}| P{.20}| P{.325}| P{.325}|}
    \hline
    Cell1                     & Cell2                      & Cell3                      & Cell4                     \\ \hline
    \multirow[t]{7}{=}{\ci}   & \multirow[t]{7}{=}{\cii}   & \multirow[t]{15}{=}{\ciii} & \multirow[t]{15}{=}{\civ} \\ % #1
                              &                            &                            &                           \\ % #2
                              &                            &                            &                           \\ % #3
                              &                            &                            &                           \\ % #4
                              &                            &                            &                           \\ % #5
                              &                            &                            &                           \\ % #6
                              &                            &                            &                           \\ \cline{1-2} % #7
    \multirow[t]{8}{=}{\cv}   & \multirow[t]{8}{=}{\cvi}   &                            &                           \\ % #8
                              &                            &                            &                           \\ % #9
                              &                            &                            &                           \\ % #10
                              &                            &                            &                           \\ % #11
                              &                            &                            &                           \\ % #12
                              &                            &                            &                           \\ % #13
                              &                            &                            &                           \\ % #14
                              &                            &                            &                           \\ \hline  % #15
    \multirow[t]{9}{=}{\cvii} & \multirow[t]{9}{=}{\cviii} & \multirow[t]{9}{=}{\cix}   & \multirow[t]{9}{=}{\cx}   \\  % #1
                              &                            &                            &                           \\ 
                              &                            &                            &                           \\ 
                              &                            &                            &                           \\ 
                              &                            &                            &                           \\ 
                              &                            &                            &                           \\ 
                              &                            &                            &                           \\
                              &                            &                            &                           \\
                              &                            &                            &                           \\ \hline  % #9
\end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a very fine solution! it works perfectly. Many thanks.